# Create column with multiple selection criteria for containing string values

Tags: string, pandas, function, contains

I have a large dataframe and I'm trying to create a column that returns the total_amount value if the conditions are satisfied.
If the first column contains any of the values in the list val1 AND
if any ONE of the columns (second, third, fourth) contain any of the values in lists targets & targets2

```
first       second   third        fourth     total_amount 
Top;Tier    None     FIT,Special   Rising      5000
Internal    None     None          Black       6000
None        Existing None          Pink        800



def func(row):
   val1 = ['primary','Internal', 'found','Led', 'Yes - found']
   targets = ['Top', 'Special', 'FIT', 'Global', 'Silver', 'Gold']
   targets2= ['Top','Gold','Beginner','Rising','Global','Excluded']

   if row['first'].str.contains('|'.join(val1)) and \
( row['second'].str.contains('|'.join(targets)) or row['third'].str.contains('|'.join(targets)) or row['fourth'].str.contains('|'.join(targets2)) ):
       return row['total_amount']
   else:
       return 0


df['verified_amount']= df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

expected output:

```
first       second   third        fourth   total_amount verified_amt
Top;Tier    None     FIT,Special   Rising      5000        5000
Internal    None     None          Black       6000        6000
None        Existing None          Pink        800          0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create conditions separately, also is possible join `second` with `third` column by [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) and set new column by chained conditions with `|` for bitwise `OR` or `&` for bitwise `AND` with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
val1 = ['primary','Internal', 'found','Led', 'Yes - found']
targets = ['Top', 'Special', 'FIT', 'Global', 'Silver', 'Gold']
targets2= ['Top','Gold','Beginner','Rising','Global','Excluded']

m1 = df['first'].str.contains('|'.join(val1))
m2 = df['second'].str.cat(df['third'], na_rep='').str.contains('|'.join(targets))
m3 = df['fourth'].str.contains('|'.join(targets2))

df['verified_amount'] = np.where(m1 | m2 | m3, df['total_amount'], 0)
#if need AND with OR - but different output from sample data
#df['verified_amount'] = np.where(m1 & (m2 | m3), df['total_amount'], 0)
print (df)
      first    second        third  fourth  total_amount  verified_amount
0  Top;Tier      None  FIT,Special  Rising          5000             5000
1  Internal      None         None   Black          6000             6000
2      None  Existing         None    Pink           800                0
```